# Mysql ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'blog_data'

Tags: mysql, drop, mysql-error-1049

I used the command `DROP DATABASE blog_data` it was executed successfully.Then I logged out of the mysql and tried to login again with the command `sudo mysql -u djangouser -p` it prompt for the password after which if I give the password it is throwing the error

> ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'blog_data'

Please help me where I am going wrong.

Comment: When you have dropped the database then why you are expecting it should be recognized?

Comment: I just want to login into the mysql client to see other databases.But I don't know why this error is coming.

Comment: Looks as user `jangouser` have not permissions to other databases. Try to login with `root`  `sudo mysql -uroot -p`

Comment: With `DROP DATABASE` you just delete the WHOLE database, so your database can't exist anymore. Like pointed out before.